# App crashes while changing the orientation from landscape to portrait

Tags: java, android, android-studio

ERROR 
**2020-03-01 17:36:58.959 6589-6589/com.studenthelper.bscit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.studenthelper.bscit, PID: 6589
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.studenthelper.bscit/com.studenthelper.bscit.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2914)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4785)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4694)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.studenthelper.bscit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7131)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4785) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4694) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)  **

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.logotext);
    int unicode=0x1F4A1;
    String emoji=getEmoji(unicode);
    String Text="Bsc"+emoji+"T";
    textView.setText(Text);

}
public String getEmoji(int uni)
{
    return new String(Character.toChars(uni));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your crash logs:

```
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) Caused by: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at 
com.studenthelper.bscit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
```

It means your **textView**

```
TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.logotext);
```

Is not found from the layout ***R.layout.activity_main*** due to which when you try to `textView.setText(Text);` it's actually **null** and exception occurs.

So, I'll suggest to

1. Verify **textVIew** Id is same in the layout? and
2. Set the `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`
    
   before the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.logotext);
    int unicode=0x1F4A1;
    String emoji=getEmoji(unicode);
    String Text="Bsc"+emoji+"T";
    textView.setText(Text);

}
```

Comment: if it worked don't forget to accept the answer, so that other's can also take benefit from your problem.

Comment: **It didn't work bro but thanks for suggest actually I have made 2 layout one for landscape and one for portrait in landscape mode I have the text view which displays my logo but in portrait mode I don't have text view. Please help**

Comment: @abhishek if you have 2 layouts than it in both layouts it should have same textview also

Answer (score 0):

To summarise the problem: You have defined two layouts, which one of them does not have a `TextView`. From your code obviously the crash is caused by calling `.setText()` on a null object.

The best way is always to add back the missing `TextView` back to your another layout, so all your layouts contains the same set of IDs. This can avoid bugs caused by `findViewById()`. In the layout which you do not need the `TextView`, you can simply set its `android:visibility="gone"` to hide it.

Alternatively back to your code, if you know the `TextView` is not always there, you can simply check if your `textView` variable is `null` or not, before calling `.setText()`. This can also avoid the `NullPointerException`.